# Is there any way to create an action counter for a script? (Python)

Tags: python, action, counter

I am using a script that analyzes a large number in two different ways, and I want to check how many actions are being used by each way. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by "action"?

Comment: well, lets say I have a large number and I want to count the naughts in it. one script is a loop that checks if the number is 0mod10 - that would be action number one, then clears the last digit - that would be action number 2, over and over again. the other one is a for loop, that runs for every digit - action number one, and compares it to zero - action number two.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean inspecting the byte code?

Comment: I don't know what does that mean. I was as clear as I could be...

Comment: Yes there are ways to do that. However, do you perhaps prefer to see how fast your different solutions are?

Comment: I know about the time functions, and this is what I'm trying to answer - what causes the difference between each script's runtime

Comment: See `timeit` in the standard library

Comment: thanks, but I don't need a timer, I'm already using one. I just need what I' specified

Comment: @Triumphan In that case you can use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)

Comment: @Triumphan You can **not** determine the bottlenecks by a counter. Also, cProfile already contains "counters". I highly suggest using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess as you are not providing any code examples of what you are doing. But if I understand correctly your program will execute a series of actions, depending on the input, and you want to know how many of these actions are performed.

You can do this by adding a variable to the beginning of your code and setting it to zero:

```
counter = 0
```

Then, after each of the parts in your code you count as an 'action', increment this `counter` variable. You might need to use the `global` keyword:

```
def doSomething():
    # Calculate some fancy stuff here
    global counter
    counter += 1
```

So at the end of your program, you should be able to get the total count by looking at your `counter` variable.